# Does VS.NET 2010 support setting up sub-projects for web applications?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have been looking for a solution for breaking up a large enterprise web application into smaller more-manageable modules and be able to build and deploy individual sub projects while at the same time have each sub-project inherit from a common set of resources such as master page, parent Page class, app_code, css, etc.

I found a workaround for setting this up in VS 2005/2008. in a [Visual Web Developer Team Blog Post](https://web.archive.org/web/20120730140143/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2006/07/01/652986.aspx) .

Question is: Is there a new approach to solving to this problem in VS 2010 (apparently the same workaround mentioned above doesn't work for VS2010). Or perhaps I'm going down the wrong road altogether; although it makes sense to me that this would be the desired way to setup large enterprise applications, if not whats the industry standard or best practice?

Your help and comments are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Break your solution in an organized manner identifying major blocks and separating thins the way that best fit your needs.

A good example to get started is nopCommerce that can be found at [codeplex](http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets). An older version (web forms) is  also available.